# Split xml using XSLT to multiple files using Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, transform, saxon

I have a XML file while needs to be split based on the match(Contains) on the Xpath variable.

```
`<Apps>
    <App>
        <AppID>49O</AppID>
        <Type>MP Pay</Type>
    </App>
    <App>
        <AppID>715</AppID>
        <Type>DP Pay</Type>
    </App>
    <App>
        <AppID>716</AppID>
        <Type>MP Pay</Type>
    </App>
    <App>
        <AppID>725</AppID>
        <Type>CP Pay</Type>
    </App>
    <App>
        <AppID>728</AppID>
        <Type>MP Pay</Type>
    </App>
   <App>
        <AppID>728</AppID>
        <Type>CP Pay</Type>
    </App>
</Apps>`
```

So conditions to split the xml is 
1. Apps/App/Type/text()-> Contains 'MP'
2. Apps/App/Type/text()-> Contains 'DP'

**Below are the expected outputs:**

1. All App nodes containing Type as 'MP' should be in a file -> MP.xml.

   `<Apps>
       <App>
           <AppID>49O</AppID>
           <Type>MP Pay</Type>
       </App>
       <App>
           <AppID>716</AppID>
           <Type>MP Pay</Type>
       </App>
       <App>
           <AppID>728</AppID>
           <Type>MP Pay</Type>
       </App>
   </Apps>`
2. All App nodes containing Type as 'DP' should be in a file -> DP.xml.

   `<Apps>
       <App>
           <AppID>715</AppID>
           <Type>DP Pay</Type>
       </App>
   </Apps>`
3. All App nodes Failed to match the above 2 conditions should be in file -> Mismatched.xml.

   `<Apps>
       <App>
           <AppID>715</AppID>
           <Type>CP Pay</Type>
       </App>
       <App>
           <AppID>725</AppID>
           <Type>CP Pay</Type>
       </App>
   </Apps>`

**Java Code**

```
public class Splitter {

    public static void transform(String sourcePath, String xsltPath,
            String resultDir) {

        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(
                    new File(xsltPath)));
            transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(sourcePath)),
                    new StreamResult(new File(resultDir)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Set saxon as transformer.
        System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
                "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");

        String inputFilepath = "resources\\InputFile.xml";
        String transformXsltPath = "resources\\Transform.xslt";
        String outputDir = "D://Tmp//";

        transform(inputFilepath, transformXsltPath, outputDir);
        System.out.println("Completed");
    }

}
```

Comment: could you post your java code as well? Do you use Saxon, plain Java (with xslt 2.0)?
Thanks,
Stephan

Comment: Yes am using Saxon. Added java code in my question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="Apps">
      <xsl:result-document href="MP.xml">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="App[contains(Type, 'MP')]"/>
         </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:result-document>
      <xsl:result-document href="DP.xml">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="App[contains(Type, 'DP')]"/>
         </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:result-document>
      <xsl:result-document href="Mismatched.xml">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="App[not(contains(Type, 'MP') or contains(Type, 'DP'))]"/>
         </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:result-document>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. Working Perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that's more rule-based:

```
<xsl:template match="App[starts-with(Type, 'MP')]" mode="group">MP</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="App[starts-with(Type, 'DP')]" mode="group">DP</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="App" mode="group">Mismatched</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="f:key" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="e" as="element(App)"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="group"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="Apps">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="App" group-by="f:key(.)">
      <xsl:result-document href="{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
         <Apps>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
         </Apps>
      </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```